# Use a formula by Group in excel

Tags: excel, group-by

I want to count how many games have past for a particular team to have as a game result a tie. I made a search and i found that for this reason i could use the Match() function, which i did and it worked. The problem is that i want to calculate this by team, and not by whole, as you will see at my linked file. I considered use Pivot table or subtotals but i didn't manage to find a workaround. Does anyone have something to suggest?

You can see the data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_Yf9GS73seQ3FRdVhWX21LQ3c/view?usp=sharing

It's an xlsx file

Thank you in advance

Comment: What went wrong with pivot tables?  This is probably the easiest way to do groupings along the lines of what you describe.

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, Pivot is the easiest way to get the calulations

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that with pivot. Can you suggest something? I can group by team but i can't tell to match function to be calculated only by team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, it should cover everything:

`J2` formula:

```
=IF(E2="Tie",COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)-1,0)
```

`K2` formula:

```
=IF(J2=0,0,ROW(J2))
```

`L2` formula:

```
=IF(AND(E2="Tie",E1="Tie"),0,IF(J2=0,1,IF(MAX($K1:K$2)>0,SUM(INDIRECT("L"&ROW(L1)&":L"&MAX($K1:K$2)+1)),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1)))
```

It is artificial lookup, couldn't think of anything better.

**Note**: Sort by club name first to get accurate results!